# How to install python from source without internet connection?

Tags: python, installation

I'm installing python on custom location on a internal server.
Unfortunately, I can't make full internet connection here. Most of sites are block by firewall. (essentially pypi repository!) Please don't ask the reason. And I don't have root account, so I have to install python from source.
I did install python from source successfully! But the problem is any of `easy_install` or `pip` is not installable because the sites are not accessible form here. :(

How can I install them under current situation?

Comment: Are there restrictions on removable media (USB thumb drives, etc)? Sorry to hear that you have to put up with such a lock down.

Comment: Server is on remote location... I'm on SSH.

Comment: Can you get to localhost on a non standard port? For instance, could you compile lighttpd in your home directory and run it on `127.0.0.1:9876`? You should be able to run a local mirror for easy_install that way, if you scp an archive of all the stuff to the document root.

Comment: cant you create a virtualenv in your local system and transfer it there?

Comment: Local mirror idea is so nice. I will try this!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Download the source tarballs of the module you are interested in to your PC
2. Upload it to the remote server (SCP)
3. Extract the tarball (eg. `tar -xvzf pack.tar.gz`)
4. Set the current directory to the extracted folder (should contain a file named `setup.py`)
5. Install the module: `python setup.py install` (See [documentation](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#the-new-standard-distutils))

*In my eyes setting up a local mirror like proposed by Tim is not worth of it (Of course this depends on how often you plan to install/update Python modules on that remote machine...)*

Comment: I solved this problem exactly same way with this answer. What I didn't know was I could install `easy_install` with `python setup.py install` command. Anyway I got bunch of problems when I try to install `markdoc` package because it needs a lot of dependencies. Maybe the mirror approach will suit to me more.

Comment: How do I find the source tarball? Is there a repo where I can find tarballs for all packages? e.g. python-dev

Comment: All the tarball's are on [pythons website](https://python.org) @rrlamichhane under downloads

Comment: When I try this I get an error: `pyconfig.h: No Such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

Download the source tarballs of the relevant modules and install them locally.

Comment: Worth noting, a [local mirror](http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2007/11/easy_install_tip_setting_up_yo.html) would provide the usual experience with easy_install, provided the OP has some facility of making one.

Answer (score 0):

```
easy_install /your/file/location/pack.tar.gz
```